# How can I use specificity to fix a CSS problem using Extenal sheets with multiple classes within a p tag?

Tags: css-specificity

Below is an **index.html** page with `five <p> elements` inside a `<div> element` and a `<body> element`

```
<body>
      <div>
        <p class='normal'>Normal and green!</p>
        <p class='normal orange small'>Small and orange!</p>
        <p class='normal orange violet large'>Large and violet!</p>
        <p class='orange'>I am orange!</p>
        <p class='violet'>I am violet!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Below is the **index.css** page containing the styles to be applied to the `<body>` of the `index.html` page.

```
body {
font-size: 15px;
}

.violet {
  color: violet;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.orange {
   color: orange;
   font-weight: 800;
}

.large {
   font-size: 25px;
}

.small {
   font-size: 12px;
}

.normal {
   font-size: 16px;
   color: green;
}
```

Therefore, without using

1. `!important`
2. `rearranging, deleting or adding to the style rules.`
3. `deleting, rearranging or adding to the classes within the HTML.`

I have included the other class attributes within the

paragraph tags as follows:

```css
body {
font-size: 15px;
}

.violet {
  color: violet;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.orange {
   color: orange;
   font-weight: 800;
}

.normal.orange.violet.large {
   font-size: 30px;
}

.normal.orange.small {
   font-size: 12px;
}

.normal {
   font-size: 16px;
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Specificty</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <p class='normal'>Normal and green!</p>
        <p class='normal orange small'>Small and orange!</p>
        <p class='normal orange violet large'>Large and violet! </p>
        <p class='orange'>I am orange!</p>
        <p class='violet'>I am violet!</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When running the code, the second and third paragraphs display the wrong color. Is it possible for the correct color to be displayed using specificity without including the color class in the CSS external stylesheet like some of the others?

Comment: You really shouldn't ask for homework solutions here

Answer (score 0):

As `.normal` is a parent style, you have to place its CSS class on top of the CSS file.

Here is a working solution for you.

```css
body {
font-size: 12px;
}

/*this is a parent  */
.normal {
   font-size: 18px;
   color: blue;
}

.brown {
  color: brown;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.red {
   color: red;
   font-weight: 700;
}

.large {
   font-size: 24px;
}

.small {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div>
        <p class='normal'>Normal and blue text!</p>
        <p class='normal red small'>Small and red text!</p>
        <p class='normal large brown'>Large and brown text!</p>
        <p class='red'>I am red....</p>
        <p class='brown'>I am brown..</p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Please learn and try these. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp .

**TIP**: When you use the same type of CSS selectors( ex: class selectors) for the same element(s), you must place parent selectors on top of the other effecting styles

**Reason**: Equal specificity: the latest rule counts - If the same rule is written twice into the external style sheet, then the lower rule in the style sheet is closer to the element to be styled, and therefore will be applied

Comment: Thank you @Nisuga Jayawardana. Let us say you have the class selector for the first paragraph is             <p class"normal">This text is red!</p>            and then the subsequent paragraphs also have a similar class selector in conjunction with other accompanying class selectors within the same paragraph such as                                                    <p class"normal green x-large>This text is Green!</p>  How can it be re-written using the class specificity rule in the external stylesheet? is it .normal.green. x-large or .green.normal.x-large or x-large.normal.green?

Comment: Never do that way. Look at the solution clearly. Learn to [inspect](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/f1-u2-chrome-inspector ) (F12) your web pages. Watch how CSS rules are overridden. from the style tab.